# Integral of $1/(ax^2 +bx +c)^n$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

How can we obtain the recursion relation for the integral of the following [rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions#Integrands_of_the_form_xm_.2F_.28a_x2_.2B_b_x_.2B_c.29n)?

$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{(ax^2 +bx +c)^n} 
&= \frac{ 2ax+b }{ (n-1) (4ac-b^2) (ax^2 +bx +c)^{n-1} }   \\
&+ \frac{ 2a (2n-3) }{ (n-1) (4ac-b^2) } \int \frac{dx}{(ax^2 +bx +c)^{n-1}}
\end{align}
$$

**NB:** This question is not similar to any previous question. In older questions they do not derive the recursion relation.

Thank you,

Comment: FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7Dx%7D%7B(ax%5E2%20%2Bbx%20%2Bc)%5En%7D%24&p=1), I found [Calculate indefinite integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/913046/602049) and [Indefinite Integral of $n$-th power of Quadratic Denominator](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/812720/602049) which may be of help. Also, in the "Related" section on the right, there's [Indefinite Integral of $\frac{1}{(ax^2+bx+c)^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/811772/602049).

Comment: If you already have this formula: differentiate both sides (which eliminates the integrals) and check an equality of rational functions.

Comment: The check is small enough that [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FullSimplify%5BD%5B%282*a*x%2Bb%29%2F%28%28n-1%29*%284*a*c-b%5E2%29*%28a*x%5E2%2Bb*x%2Bc%29%5E%28n-1%29%29%2Cx%5D%2B%282*a*%282n-3%29%29%2F%28%28n-1%29*%284*a*c-b%5E2%29*%28a*x%5E2%2Bb*x%2Bc%29%5E%28n-1%29%29%5D) can show it. Don't worry about the time out, it is timing out because it also wants to give you other information about the function like it's Taylor series at different points and that it is what is running out of time on. The pure simplification appears without that timeout.

Answer (score 1):

For ease of notation, I define $y \equiv ax^2 +bx +c$, so $y’=2ax+b$, $y’’=2a$, and $\Delta^2 \equiv b^2-4ac$. We perform integration by part for $\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y^{n-1}}$:
$$
2a \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y^{n-1}}  = \int \frac{y’’}{y^{n-1}} \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{y’}{y^{n-1}} +(n-1) \int \frac{(y’)^2}{y^n} \mathrm{d}x
$$
Using the identity $y=\frac{1}{4a} \left( y’^2 -\Delta^2 \right)$, the above integral can be written as:
$$
2a \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y^{n-1}}  = \frac{y’}{y^{n-1}}
+4a(n-1) \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x }{y^{n-1}}   +(n-1) \Delta^2 \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x }{y^n}
$$
and the proof is complete:
$$
\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x }{y^n} = \frac{-1}{(n-1) \Delta^2} 
\left[ 2a(2n-3) \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x }{y^{n-1}} +\frac{y’}{y^{n-1}} \right]
$$